# How can i find not changing point in array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of values. I want to find the not changing point  (index) in that list. For example:

```
array = [ a, b, b, a, b, a, a, a, b, b, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, .... , a, a, a]
                                        .
```

I want result as 10 (index)

Or

```
array = [a, b, a, b, b, b, b, b]
                  .
```

I want result as 3 (index)

How can I find this?

Comment: Why not 1 in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want your result to be the total count whether starting from the left, any item is not equal to the previous item :

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
total_changes = sum([1 for i,j in zip(array, array[1:]) if i!=j])
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the array from the reverse, you just want the index where it changes. You can find the index from the end and subtract it from the length. Using an iterator and `next()` will let you do this without going through the whole list:

```
array = [ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']

try:
    r_index = next((i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(array)) if v != array[-1]))
    i = len(array) - r_index
except StopIteration:
    i =  0

print(i) #10
```

the `try/except` is for cases of empty or 1 item arrays.